# How to format text in a string array to math format for android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse, math

I have an app that helps people with Calculus and I would like to make it look like actual math code than an equation looking like x^2+(x^1/2)-4. The code in the project is below. I've researched about this topic and I do not see a clear cut solution. Thanks!

```
public class Limits extends Activity implements
    OnClickListener {
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

String facts[] = {

//limits
"Find the limit as x approaches 0 of x^3+4x^2+6x+7",
"Find the limit as x approaches infinity of x/x^2",
"Find the limit as x approaches 3 of (x+3)^2/(x+6)",
"Find the limit as x approaches infinity of x^3/x",
"Find the limit as x approaches 3 of (x^2-6x+9)/(x-3)",
"Find the limit as x approaches 7 of 49x^2/7x",
"Find the limit as x approaches infinity of (2x^2-5x+3)/(x^2-7x+7)",
"Find the limit as x approaches 2 of (x − 2/x^2 − 19x + 34)",
"Find the limit as x approaches 6 of ((|x-6|)/(x-6))",
```

};

Comment: What does "actual math code" mean?  "x^2+(x^1/2)-4" looks like a mathematical equation to me.  About the only thing it doesn't have is superscript for the exponential powers.

Comment: Right how do you enable superscript? I mean math code in general like this. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/math/immath/intalg.gif

Comment: Looking at the examples you've pointed to, and assuming the annotation used is *everything* you want to use, then the only pieces which are not easy to do are the divisor and the root annotations.  The only way I can think to do these is to extend TextView, override the onDraw() and draw the text by hand.  Also take a look at Spannables, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html,   If you do this, I'd recommend that you consider making it a library and publishing it.  I'm sure you would get users...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use HTML:

```
Html.fromHtml("X<sup>2</sup>")
```

Comment: So it's been a while and the html did work for that but how do you get division to work.